# JQuery ajax call - can't pass url parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sorry for this "newbe" question.

Here is my problem:

I am using JQuery 1.8.2 and I am trying to issue an ajax request:

This is working:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://191.168.0.133/rest/interface/test/1',
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        var registrationInfo = '<h1>' + item.testID+ '</h1>';
                        output.append(registrationInfo);
                    });
                },
        error: function(){
                output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

But I want the URL Parameter to be passed by a variable. The folloing is not working, but always ending up in the error function "There was an error loading the data."

```
    var testURL = 'http://191.168.0.133/rest/interface/test/1';
    $.ajax({
        url: testURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
                $.each(data, function(i,item){
                        var registrationInfo = '<h1>' + item.testID+ '</h1>';
                        output.append(registrationInfo);
                    });
                },
        error: function(){
                output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
            }
        });
```

I am going bonkers over this. Can anyone give me a hand?
Thanks in advance ...

Comment: So the first ajax call with the inline url works?

Comment: @David maybe this is the first newbie ajax question where the asynchronicity is not the problem :-)

Comment: The ; in the var-line did not get pasted. It is there and this is not working. All I get is the "There was an error loading the data" when I try to use the variable instead of writing out the URL.

Comment: Just out of interest... ignoring the url part for the moment...  you say it is a datatype of json, but you don't pass any data... do your results change if you pass anything?

Comment: I am getting data. The above piece works, it fetches id:1 from the URL and returns a test value.

Answer (score 4):

I think adding a semicolon after the url will fix your issue.

If there was a semicolon then I'd suggest posting a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and try
if you can get it down to the bare differences that cause the error.

Comment: Sorry the ; did not paste ... it is there and still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have mentioned seems to be fine.
I guess you might be ignoring something else ... anyways, just to guide you with a few suggestions:

- You said it is not working ... Do you mean you are getting a syntax error? You can check it in the browser console. F12 key opens the console in most browsers. OR open the error console from the browser menu and see. Or does the error function execute
- You might like to put a semi-colon at the end of each "statement" (like variable declaration, variable assignments) to avoid a beginner's confusions due to the "automatic semi-colon insertion" feature of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around the problem.

While the $.ajax command is still not working, i switched to $.getJSON and this works:

```
    var testURL = 'http://191.168.0.133/rest/interface/test/1';
    $.getJSON(testURL, function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){
                    var registrationInfo = '<h1>' + item.testID+ '</h1>';
                    output.append(registrationInfo);
                });
            };
```

No clue still, why the $.ajax thing won't work, since getJSON is only a shorthand for the ajax command.